# Problem in booting my computer

Tags: 14.04, boot, gnome, live-usb, reboot

While installing windows i accidentally deleted all my files and could not install windows either. Now when i am trying to restart my computer it says no boot device found. I also tried reinstall Ubuntu with pen drive but still can't able to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

please boot from a 'bootable USB' device (I do not mean reinstall)/ for example run Ubuntu live and if it works, then the problem is probably your HDD. Please give me feedback because I need to dig deeper into your problem... Thanks.